# Como adicionar um span num htmlhelper?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Eu tenho este helper

```
 <li>@Html.ActionLink("Registar", "Register", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "registerLink"})</li>
```

Queria adicionar esse **`<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user">`**

```
 <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Registar</a></li>
```

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza engraçado em portugal se escreve Registar

Comment: Diversidade da língua Portuguesa :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Essa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1974980/putting-html-inside-html-actionlink-plus-no-link-text) do [@David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/87416/david) no **SO** sugere usar o `Url.Action` em vez do `ActionLink`.

Ficaria assim:

```
<li>
    <a href="@Url.Action("Register", "Account")">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"/> Registrar
    </a>
</li>
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Funcionou assim '<li><a href="@Url.Action("Register","Account")"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"/> Registrar</a></li>'